# How to expose combobox Databindings on a usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a *combobox* on a *usercontrol*. I can expose the datasource however I cant expose the actual bindings.

If you add a normal *combobox* to a form and go to the databindings property you can choose selected value, text etc.

After this is chosen the designer automatically creates a

`combobox.databindings.add("SelectedValue", datasource, columname, true));`

How can I expose a *combobox* on a user control so that it has the above behavior

Comment: i might be missing the point but whats wrong with having a method on the usercontrol to set the databinding or accessing the combo box via `usercontrol.combobox.databindings`?

Comment: I had that originally. It works however it seems clunky. I want the combobox on the usercontrol to work like it normally works via the designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not considered best practice to expose your controls like this since after all, part of the point of using a UserControl is to hide the details of the child controls.

Try exposing the control on the UserControl as a property:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
  public UserControl1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public ComboBox ComboBox {
    get {
      return this.comboBox1;
    }
  }
}
```

If you are only interested in the control's DataBindings, then try to just expose that information:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
  public UserControl1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public ControlBindingsCollection ComboDataBindings {
    get {
      return this.comboBox1.DataBindings;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet your second example Worked! It was that simple